# Actionscript load external sound file from php and find out the actual filename from the php response?

Tags: php, flash, audio, actionscript, filenames

My as3 code to load external sound:

```
var s:Sound = new Sound(); 
s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded); 
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("getfile.php"); 
s.load(req); 

function onSoundLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    var localSound:Sound = event.target as Sound; 
    localSound.play(); 
}
```

Then my php code to return the file:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

In onSoundLoaded event, how do i get the actual filename return from the php response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way to solve the problem is to use URLLoader http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html to load the data instead of using the Sound class. This is because you can listen to the HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event:httpResponseStatus event that wraps the response headers (which include the filename). The listener for event complete can be used unmodified as in your code because it returns the same data.

```
    var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded); 
    loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, onStatusResonse);
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("getfile.php"); 
    s.load(req); 

    function onStatusResonse(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void 
    { 
       var headers:Array = event.responseHeaders;
       // iterate on headers to get the header with the filename
    }

   function onSoundLoaded(event:Event):void 
    { 
       var localSound:Sound = event.target as Sound; 
       localSound.play(); 
    }
```

The solution is not exactly what you want (finding the file name in onSoundLoaded function), but I think it is the best way to go. Hope it helps